# How to disable logging for MATLAB's fuzzy c-means clustering?

Tags: matlab, logging, fuzzy-c-means

I work with `fcm` in MATLAB. I need to turn off logging in command windows. What is the best way to accomplish this?

For example, when I run the command I get the following printed to the MATLAB command window

```
>> fcm(dok, 7)

Iteration count = 1, obj. fcn = 8.970479 
Iteration count = 2, obj. fcn = 7.197402 
Iteration count = 3, obj. fcn = 6.325579
Iteration count = 4, obj. fcn = 4.586142
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fourth element of [`options`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html#inputarg_options) array input to `0` to indicate that you don't want to display the results from every iteration.

```
[centers, U, objfun] = fcm(dok, 7, [2, 100, 1e-5, 0])
```

Alternately, you can use [`evalc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to suppress *all* command line output from a function.

```
[~, centers , U, objfun] = evalc('fcm(dok, 7)');
```

Comment: The problem is that I only have two inputs. Example: [center,'matrix,obj_fcn] = fcm(dok, 7);

Comment: @BranislavPažický Right, that's why I've used an options vector that uses all default values (shown in the documentation) except for the fourth element.